# Whats a good way to test Dom heavy js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, selenium

I have a bunch of JS code that relies heavily on dom elements. The testing solution I'm using currently relies on selenium, but AFAIK its not possible to properly evaluate js errors (`addScript` errors will not cause your tests to fail, and `getEval` does'nt seem to run the javascript in the actual window).

I'm wondering what is a good way to test JS that needs dom in a variety of browsers, in a way that will cause tests to fail?

Comment: Use actual client-side testing with `QUnit` and use `Browserling` to do the testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/).  It's a nice Javascript testing framework with a community that's provided many plugins, including plugins for making testing jQuery and ajax requests easier.  The [jasmine-jquery](http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2010/07/29/html-fixtures-in-jasmine-using-jasmine-jquery/) plugin allows you to load DOM fixtures from separate HTML files and you can then run your tests against those fixtures.

Another nice thing about Jasmine is that it can easily be used in continuous integration environments, because it takes care of launching a web browser, running the tests in the web browser, and collecting information about what tests passed and failed and reporting that information in the console.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.phantomjs.org/

It is a full webkit browser, so you have a full DOM/BOM model, and all of the events available to you that you'd get in a "real" browser.

Note, this isn't a full solution, because it won't simulate a gecko or IE or Opera browser, but if you're just regression testing your code, rather than performing extensive cross-platform testing, PhantomJS looks perfect for you.

Other solutions to explore would be [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/)

Answer (score 1):

qUnit is a nice js testing library. 
http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit

I guess you can't catch JS-errors as qUnit is also written in JS.

However it allows you to write very detailed tests which would fail if an error occured.

Comment: Interesting -- looks like maybe i can hook up qunit to selenium